# NodeJS & NPM: Package Security

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm

Given how popular NodeJS is, and how NPM works... what is the best way to ensure you never install an insecure / malware package? To me this seems to be a huge gaping hole in the architecture, relying solely on user reviews, comments on sites like StackOverflow, personal blogs, etc. I've done a little searching and all I can seem to find is a "plan" for removing offending users once a complaint is filed that said users broke the code of conduct.

NPM Code of Conduct
https://www.npmjs.com/policies/conduct

Here's how you publish a package...
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

So I started thinking about what kind of bad things someone could do... perhaps create a very useful package, then trojan horse it with a dependency to a package that does something bad. Even if I (as the installer) reviewed the packages I personally install, I probably would never catch the offending code, especially if the code was obfuscated, like this:

```
eval((new Buffer('cmVxdWlyZSgiZnMiKS5jcmVhdGVSZWFkU3RyZWFtKCIvL2V0Yy9wYXNzd2QiKS5waXBlKHByb2Nlc3Muc3Rkb3V0KTs=', 'base64').toString()));
```

This code simply echoes the /etc/passwd file to your standard out. Nothing more. Prove it by running just this:

```
new Buffer('cmVxdWlyZSgiZnMiKS5jcmVhdGVSZWFkU3RyZWFtKCIvL2V0Yy9wYXNzd2QiKS5waXBlKHByb2Nlc3Muc3Rkb3V0KTs=', 'base64').toString()
```

Those of you who catch the eval, good for you! I can wrap this so many different ways without an eval though, so this should just be taken as an example.

So, with all of that said... what is the community doing to deal with this eventuality? Where can I find more on how to keep my systems secure?

Comment: The whole community security is based on faith and hope that everything will be alright.

Comment: I think the fact that all packages must be open-sourced makes it quite hard for someone to sneak in something malicious. Even looking at the code without the eval, the text with no apparent purpose is alarming. You can also look by numbers of dependents of the package and also check on its repo for issues posted, how many people have read the code enough to submit pull requests, etc.

Comment: open source is based on trust _and_ verification

Comment: I do find it a tad bit alarming that any person can upload a package. However, I do not know of a decent way of verifying that the user isn't malicious.

Comment: All we can do now (for the time being) is go through each of our dependencies dependencies and their dependencies and their ... (recursive wording, much?) and look at their internal workings.

Comment: Unless someone were to make a module that required no external dependencies, and would check all of our dependencies for "buzz words," or things that are obscure ( or down right malicious ) that really should be given a second look at.

Comment: This is certainly a concern, but this is not limited to `npm` and applies to any software installation at all. Different package managers have different measures to protect against this. Node's is essentially openness and community review. You can report malicious packages to support@npmjs.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Update on Oct 5th, 2022**

Running a security audit using npm is much simpler now.

```
$ npm audit
```

[Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-audit) is here.

## **Outdated answer**

One of possible solutions to make sure that packages you install from npm are secure is to use [nsp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nsp): command line utility provided by The Node Security (nodesecurity.io) team.

```
$ npm install -g nsp
```

Then, in the directory of your project (where package.json is located):

```
$ nsp check
```

Will produce a report with possible vulnerabilities, here is the example:

[image]

Comment: Is `nsp` secure? :p

Comment: good question. thats the main guy behind this initiative: https://medium.com/node-security/announcing-the-node-security-platform-28c99f872688#.ty9fgckws

Comment: Dagnabit. You beat me. I found this and meant to answer my own question. :) Anyways, I'm accepting your answer... but I'm totally against the -g on install for pretty much everything, unless you have nvm installed. [See why here](http://brokenpromises.io/2016/08/15/where-do-i-start/). I just spent 3 hours undoing some -g hackery earlier today tbh.

Comment: This answer is invalid by now - nodesecurity.io is no more. Npm acquired ^Lift Security, the company that made nsp, in 2018. https://medium.com/npm-inc/npm-acquires-lift-security-258e257ef639